# Is there any real benefit using crosswalk for Android 4.4 & above?

Tags: android, performance, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

Crosswalk plugin is very important in bringing huge performance improvement for hybrid app. But the problem is, once it is added, the APK is becoming HUGE, adding about 15-18MB of size to the installer.

So, is there any real benefit (especially in performance) for adding the crosswalk into the installer for Android 4.4 & above?

Comment: Android 4.4 was the last one(s) with a static (OS update only) WebView (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) With Android 5.0 and up the WebView is updatable from the Play Store. If your app works well with 4.4/4.4.3 and the updated version in 5.0+ then it makes sense to remove it.

Comment: Performance is not one of the main reasons to use XWalk. Main reason would be compatibility. Another reason is not all teams can afford to test in a wide range of devices/engines. Also get used to 40MB+ apks.

Comment: CSS Transforms do not work on Android 4.4, at least most of the ones an app of mine is using. Crosswalk saves the day for that platform.

Answer (score 3):

I recently done some performance tests of angularJS cordova app on android 4.4+ devices. I prepered short stories and tested cordova app vs cordova + crosswalk app using browser-perf utility (https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf). The only performance boost I saw was painting (aprox. 4 times faster in comparison with 'clean' cordova). All other metrics were worse, some even much worse (rendering: aprox 1.5 times slower). Summarizing times, my cordova+crosswalk app was 9% slower than cordova. Also crosswalk added 21MB to my apk size and 60MB(!) to app size after installation. In case of my project, using crosswalk was pointless because of weight and speed. App used to tests was really rich angular SPA project, maybe simple apps can achieve some boost from crosswalk.