# Does the new Android WebView perform the same as CrossWalk WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, crosswalk

I am using [CrossWalk WebView](http://crosswalk-project.org/) and as you know it extends the app size of 25 MB more, and the app size after installation goes up to 70 MB!

One thing I need to know, CrossWalk WebView supports old devices, and make the performance much better by using a better WebView instead of the default one, but as I knew after Android KitKat Google replaced the WebView with Chromium one, does that mean that using default WebView in devices running Android KitKat+ is an alternative of using CrossWalk WebView, I mean does the hybrid application performance differ between Chromium and CrossWalk WebView?

If the performance is the same, I would use default system WebView and stop supporting old Android OS.

Comment: Any help please!

Comment: People are voting up to my question and bounty is ending today, I had no answer yet, I have tested normal Cromium WebView on Android 6+ and it was really bad, obviously worse than CrossWalk WebView.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use crosswalk??

Comment: Yes of course! the very high performance with web apps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information about the performance difference of android webview and clean cordova install here in this answer (I think this will be the most relevant for you) : 
[Is there any real benefit using crosswalk for Android 4.4 & above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585423/is-there-any-real-benefit-using-crosswalk-for-android-4-4-above)

Also while choosing you will maybe like to look at what extra HTML5 features are provided by crosswalk above 4.4 devices as in android webview above kitkat some features are disabled 
Resource : Why do I need Crosswalk now that Android (KitKat and later) has a Chrome-based webview? question in https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html

Comment: So, there is no escape, I will have to go native :(
Thank you very much for the answer, I didn't notice the information in CrossWalk website FAQ page before.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia

> Crosswalk built with the latest releases of Chromium and Blink from
>   Google. These are also used in Google Chrome.

There are some points you can consider:

- Chrome for Android is separate from WebView. They're both based on
  the same code, including a common JavaScript engine and rendering
  engine.
- Crosswalk is a chromium web runtime that can be packaged with the
  app.

  Default webview doesn't support WebRTC audio/video feature but crosswalk does.
- You can debug your crossview packaged project but can not for webview.
- Crosswalk supports:

  - Icon fonts, SVG, Flexbox, and more
  - New monitoring APIs
  - File System API

Now a days most of the devices have at least Kitkat, so performance shouldn't be the issue.

If you are building a HTML5 game or want to use WebRTC for audio/audio calling you can go for crosswalk but you don't need to integrate crosswalk if you want to use basic web functionalities.

For more information [Does the new WebView have feature parity with Chrome for Android?](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_) and [Old WebView vs. Chromium backed WebView Benchmark](https://www.timroes.de/2013/11/23/old-webview-vs-chromium-webview/)

Comment: I have just opened my app in both ways, normal Cromium WebView with android 6+ and CrossWalk WebView, CrossWalk is way too better than Cromium WebView! my app is a normal web app made with `Framework7`, simple page animations are very slow and the screen sensitivity also, while in CrossWalk it almost feels native.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Chrome and its webview both are different but based on same code and engine, while crosswalk is standalone webview, it directly renders a view using its own engine and native classes/code, while native webview is kind of wrapper around chromium, that's why they have a difference in performance.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information you provided, I guess that there is no escape, I will have to go native.